# In Salesforce LWC lightning-datatable unable find the current selected or un selected record

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, web-components

In Salesforce LWC lightning-datatable unable find the current selected or un selected record

As per documentation "onrowselection" call back always giving records which is selected. I need to fetch which records is currently selected/unselected.

Comment: Here is a full working sample, might help you: https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/03/24/lightning-web-components-datatable-with-lazy-loading-inline-edit-and-dynamic-row-action/

Comment: I don't want lazyloading/infinite scroll for my app. I need to show pagination and use can navigate from page to page to see record

Comment: that's just an addon. You can remove that from code.